# pring-cloud-skipper-server upgradation issue

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-skipper

I am using a stack under that having an spring-cloud-skipper-server container previous version was 2.6.1 tried to upgrade to 2.9.2 from that container was not in up state

having this error message
Err": "starting container failed: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./wait-for-it.sh": stat ./wait-for-it.sh: no such file or directory: unknown",

i want to make this container up